# Accessibility of variables and functions within my classes

Tags: java, .net, oop

I have 2 questions, but they are about the same (similar?) problem.

**First question:**

```
public class A {

    public void myProcedure() {
        doSomethingA();
    }

    private void doSomethingA() {}

}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void myProcedure() {
        doSomethingB();
        // IT DOESN'T CALL super.myProcedure
    }

    private void doSomethingB() {}

}

public class C extends B {

    @Override
    public void myProcedure() {
        // I need to execute A's myProcedure here
    }

}
```

How to run `A`'s `myProcedure`, without setting `doSomethingA` to `public`?

**Second question:**

I create my own `TextBox`, there is a variable named `myValue`. Now I create an `AdvancedTextBox` that inherits `TextBox`, and `AdvancedTextBox` need to access `myValue` variable. The problem is, I want future developer using both `TextBox` and `AdvancedTextBox`, or inherit them can't access `myValue`. Is it possible?

**EDIT:** Oli Charlesworth and NullUserException ఠ_ఠ tell me to let C inherit A directly (first question). However, there's some cases this can be disaster. For example: A = TextBox, B = AdvancedTextBox, C = NumberAdvancedTextBox, if C inherits A, so C have to do everything that B does again, with some small changes.

Comment: First: make it protected, not private.

Comment: By the [substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), an object of type `C` should behave like a specialisation of `B`.  If you're having to "regress" the behaviour back to that of `A`, it implies that your hierarchy is incorrect.

Comment: I agree with @OliCharlesworth. If you need to access A's methods from C, maybe C should inherit directly from A.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I've edited my question (add information at the end), to tell the case C should not inherit directly from A.

Comment: Ok, then if you stand by your hierarchy `C -> B -> A` then what's incorrect is the design of your methods. You overrode `A.myProcedure` in `B` making it impossible to call it from an instance of `C`.

Comment: Oli's point about the substitution principal still stands. If a NumberAdvancedTextBox cannot be substituted for an AdvancedTextBox and have the exact same behavior, you are not adhering to the principal.  Hoymkot's answer below is the holds the key -- composition!!!  I have seen so many poor designs resulting from a programmers infatuation with inheritance.

Comment: Also, when I see class names like AdvancedTextBox, I worry a bit.  There is not a precise semantic meaning to the adjective "Advanced", so I'm pretty sure it s just going to be a grab-bag of functionality. I wouldn't recommend inheriting from such a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this ...

- Put A and C in the same package, and then put B in a different package.
- Remove "private" from A.doSomethingA()
- Give C an instance of A. ( Favor Composition Over Inheritance )
- Since C and A are in the same package, C can call A.doSomethingA() anytime.

Here is definition of A

```
package ac; 

public class A {

    public void myProcedure() {
        doSomethingA();
    }

   void doSomethingA() {}

}
```

Here is definition of B

```
package b;

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void myProcedure() {
        doSomethingB();
        // IT DOESN'T CALL super.myProcedure
    }

    private void doSomethingB() {}

}
```

Here is definition of C

```
package ac;
// do you really need to extend B? 
public class C {
    A a = new A();

    public void myProcedure() {
        a.doSomethingA(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: C has to extend B. However, maybe `protected` can solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since doSomethingA is an implementation detail. I would change it from a private to protected to allow subclasses to call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

If some outside module calls A.myProcedure, it is not necessary for doSomethingA to be public. The other module is not calling doSomethingA directly, and that's all that matters. The deliberate intention of Java scope modifiers is that they only apply when you call a function DIRECTLY, not indirectly via another function. This way a class can have a small number of public functions that define the public interface. This can be carefully documented and very stable. Then these public functions can call any number of private functions, and you can freely shuffle these private functions around, say to improve performance, or to work with a new environment, etc, without having to change the public interface.